# How can I use IIS URL Rewrite to forward http to https node.js app?

Tags: node.js, iis

I am using URL rewrite to redirect all incoming request to my node.js app.
It works fine.

However, I want to redirect

```
http://www.example.com
```

to

```
https://www.example.com
```

I have googled the related setting.
Although, it can display the node.js web app correctly, however, the browser report that is not a secure web site.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="forward rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:9000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="http to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="https://www.example.com/" exactDestination="false" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I found that if I don't bind HTTP to the web site, it will prompt error.

Comment: 1) Delete `<httpRedirect>`. 2) Move "http to https" to top. Besides, the web site must have both HTTP and HTTPS site bindings, and ARR must have proxy mode enabled.

Comment: You may need a valid certificate for the site. open the devtools in your brower, toggle to “Security”, from here, you will be able to see what is causing your page to be not secure.